# What is the simplest way to rename Key and Value properties in Dictionary<> subclasses

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have a complex data container with multiple levels of nested Dictionaries.

But having `Key` and `Value` properties make it non-intuitive and hard to use.

Please suggest the simplest way to rename Key and Value properties in `Dictionary<,>` subclasses.

**Update:**

Patryk Ćwiek: If you implement `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, you also can't rename properties, because they're part of the contract.

You're right. My question was not correct. Usage of `KeyValuePair` in `IDictionary` restrict the pair properties to `Key` and `Value`. So if we want non Key/Value pair we had to implement `IDictionary` with custom `KeyValuePair` struct. Or may be there is some other tricky way?

PS. Maybe someone suggest an `IDictionary` code generation template?

Comment: If it's a subclass, then you can't. If you implement `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, you also can't rename properties, because they're part of the contract. What you probably could do is composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: *I have complex data container with multiple levels of nested Dictionaries.* If you're nesting them purely to have a composite key then make a `struct MyKey { string x; int y; }` but make them properties. Do the gethashcode/equality stuff. Now you don't have nested dictionaries.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek You could always do explicit interface implementation to "hide" some of the members you need to implement.

Comment: @ta.speot.is That's true. But in OP's case, it seems like he would like to break the dictionary contract, which might hint that his data structure neither should *be* nor *behave* like a `Dictionary<_,_>`/`IDictionary<_,_>`, and couldn't be substituted for one.

Comment: I agree with all the above comments, but I do disagree with the original OP who says that Key/Value property names for a Dictionary are 'non-intuitive'. If a Dictionary didn't have those properties I be slightly confused! I wonder what he wants to replace them with?

Comment: So you problem is that you get expressions like `.Value.Value.Key` and similar? Do you want to make some extension methods to `KeyValuePair<MeaningfulName, Dictionary<GoodName, NiceType>>` so you can say `.Meaningful()` instead of `.Key`, etc.? Not sure your question is clear.

Answer (score 4):

Make your own interface with the property name(s) you want. Then, have your concrete class implement your custom interface.

To keep your code DRY, create a private Dictionary that you delegate all of your work to. You can even have your custom interface be Enumerable (or anything else that `IDictionary` implements) by delegating the required methods to your private variable.

Here is an example. You would just need change your code from using `IDictionary` to `IComplexDataContainer`.

```
  interface IComplexDataContainer<TKey, TValue>
    : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>
  {
    TValue this[TKey index] { get; set; }
  }

  class MyComplexDataContainer<TKey, TValue>
    : IComplexDataContainer<TKey, TValue>
  {
    IDictionary<TKey, TValue> hiddenHelper { get; set; }

    public MyComplexDataContainer()
    {
      hiddenHelper = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    }

    // delegate all of the work to the hidden dictionary
    public TValue this[TKey index]
    {
      get
      {
        return hiddenHelper[index];
      }
      set
      {
        hiddenHelper[index] = value;
      }
    }

    // Just delegate the IEnumerable interface to your hidden dictionary
    // or any other interface you want your class to implement
    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
      return hiddenHelper.GetEnumerator();
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
      return GetEnumerator();
    }
  }
```

Then you would just use like this:

```
  IComplexDataContainer<string, int> myData = new MyComplexDataContainer<string,int>();
  myData["tom"] = 18;
  myData["dick"] = 22;
  myData["harry"] = myData["tom"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Problem is KeyValuePair that constrain Key and Value properties, which i want to rename.